# How can I name the output from my WiX Installer project based on GitVersion properties?

Tags: msbuild, wix, gitversion

I've recently started using [GitVersion](https://github.com/GitTools/GitVersion) to version my assemblies, and I love it!

I like to generate a `.msi` file that reflects the version of the product being built. Hitherto, I was using this in my `.wixproj` file:

```
  <!-- [TPL] name the output file to include the version from theLocalServer assembly -->
  <Target Name="BeforeBuild">
    <GetAssemblyIdentity AssemblyFiles="$(SolutionDir)BuildOutput\$(Configuration)\TA.DigitalDomeworks.Server.exe">
      <Output TaskParameter="Assemblies" ItemName="AssemblyVersions" />
    </GetAssemblyIdentity>
    <CreateProperty Value="$(OutputName).%(AssemblyVersions.Version)">
      <Output TaskParameter="Value" PropertyName="TargetName" />
    </CreateProperty>
    <CreateProperty Value="$(TargetName)$(TargetExt)">
      <Output TaskParameter="Value" PropertyName="TargetFileName" />
    </CreateProperty>
    <CreateProperty Value="$(TargetDir)$(TargetFileName)">
      <Output TaskParameter="Value" PropertyName="TargetPath" />
    </CreateProperty>
  </Target>
```

This produces an output file with a name like:

> TA.DigitalDomeworks.Installer.7.1.0.3.msi

I found this solution from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42028144/98516), which references [this blog post](http://blog.tentaclesoftware.com/archive/2010/08/05/99.aspx). The `7.1.0.3` comes from the assembly version of the main assembly in the build, which in turn is being versioned by GitVersion during its own build.

However, what I'd really like is to use the `FullSemVer` property, which can be seen here:

```
C:\Users\Tim\source\repos\TA.DigitalDomeworks [release/7.1 ↑1 +0 ~1 -0 !]> gitversion
{
  "Major":7,
  "Minor":1,
  "Patch":0,
  "PreReleaseTag":"beta.3",
  "PreReleaseTagWithDash":"-beta.3",
  "PreReleaseLabel":"beta",
  "PreReleaseNumber":3,
  "BuildMetaData":"",
  "BuildMetaDataPadded":"",
  "FullBuildMetaData":"Branch.release/7.1.Sha.77fa2c96ed9b0f5ab162d07052ef094e8ccfc8c5",
  "MajorMinorPatch":"7.1.0",
  "SemVer":"7.1.0-beta.3",
  "LegacySemVer":"7.1.0-beta3",
  "LegacySemVerPadded":"7.1.0-beta0003",
  "AssemblySemVer":"7.1.0.3",
  "FullSemVer":"7.1.0-beta.3",
  "InformationalVersion":"7.1.0-beta.3+Branch.release/7.1.Sha.77fa2c96ed9b0f5ab162d07052ef094e8ccfc8c5",
  "BranchName":"release/7.1",
  "Sha":"77fa2c96ed9b0f5ab162d07052ef094e8ccfc8c5",
  "NuGetVersionV2":"7.1.0-beta0003",
  "NuGetVersion":"7.1.0-beta0003",
  "CommitsSinceVersionSource":3,
  "CommitsSinceVersionSourcePadded":"0003",
  "CommitDate":"2018-09-10"
}
```

So the final filename I'd like to see is:

> TA.DigitalDomeworks.Installer-7.1.0-Beta.3.msi

In the GitVersion documentation, it say that I need to make sure the `GitVersion.GetVersion` build task has executed, after which I should be able to obtain the full SemVer from a build property called `$(GitVersion_FullSemVer)`.

However, I'm not sure how to achieve that in a WiX project, since installing the `GitVersionTask` NuGet package doesn't seem to do anything (in C# projects, everything just magically works). If I could get to the point where I can execute the `GitVersion.GetVersion` task, then I think I can see my way clear to getting the output name I want.

Has anyone got this working? Or can anyone offer any advice on how to approach this?

Comment: Note: it is apparently a bad idea to vary the output name of an installer if it is planned to use minor upgrades. However, I only ever use major upgrades in my installers so I can live with that limitation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I figured it out. I was on the right lines to start with. There's no need to manually execute `GitVersion.GetVersion`, this is handled correctly by MSBuild once the `GitVersionTask` NuGet package is installed in the WiX project. The reason it wasn't working is because I was trying to use GitVersion's properties before they had been set.

So, first thing is to create a couple of properties that disable some unwanted `GitVersion` actions:

```
  <PropertyGroup>
    <GenerateAssemblyInfo>false</GenerateAssemblyInfo>
    <WriteVersionInfoToBuildLog>false</WriteVersionInfoToBuildLog>
    <GenerateGitVersionInformation>false</GenerateGitVersionInformation>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

We can't simply change the `OutputName` property because that is set before any tasks (including `GitVersion` tasks) execute, so if we try to use the `GitVersion` properties in there, they will be empty/unset because the `GitVersion` targets haven't executed yet. Instead, we have to put some logic into a build target, the obvious candidate being the `BeforeBuild` target that is usually found at the end of the project file:

```
  <Target Name="BeforeBuild" AfterTargets="GetVersion">
    <CreateProperty Value="$(OutputName).$(GitVersion_SemVer)">
      <Output TaskParameter="Value" PropertyName="TargetName" />
    </CreateProperty>
    <CreateProperty Value="$(TargetName)$(TargetExt)">
      <Output TaskParameter="Value" PropertyName="TargetFileName" />
    </CreateProperty>
    <CreateProperty Value="$(TargetDir)$(TargetFileName)">
      <Output TaskParameter="Value" PropertyName="TargetPath" />
    </CreateProperty>
  </Target>
```

Here we use the `OutputName` property as a base name and augmented it with the desired GitVersion properties, to create the `TargetName`, `TargetFileName` and `TargetPath` properties that will be used in the rest of the build process. This works because the `BeforeBuild` task is guaranteed to execute before any output file is generated, so all the Target* properties will be set before then.

Comment: Do you want to version the wix project itself, or the main assembly project? I think what you want is the main assembly project.

Comment: @Tim Long, Great that you solved it, I remove my answer since it was not relevant.

Answer (score 1):

**Let's see if this solves your problem**

My approach goes thus:

Add the following to your main assembly project, not the wix project

```
<Target Name="WriteVersionToFile" AfterTargets="GetVersion">
        <WriteLinesToFile File="$(OutputPath)version.txt" Lines="$(GitVersion_FullSemVer)" Overwrite="true" Encoding="Unicode" /> 
</Target>
```

Then replace your BeforeBuild target with this sample in your wix project

```
<Target Name="BeforeBuild">
    <ReadLinesFromFile File="$(SolutionDir)BuildOutput\$(Configuration)\version.txt">  
        <Output TaskParameter="Lines" ItemName="Version" />  
    </ReadLinesFromFile>
    <CreateProperty Value="$(OutputName).$(Version)">
      <Output TaskParameter="Value" PropertyName="TargetName" />
    </CreateProperty>
    <CreateProperty Value="$(TargetName)$(TargetExt)">
      <Output TaskParameter="Value" PropertyName="TargetFileName" />
    </CreateProperty>
    <CreateProperty Value="$(TargetDir)$(TargetFileName)">
      <Output TaskParameter="Value" PropertyName="TargetPath" />
    </CreateProperty>
  </Target>
```

The solution adds the *GitVersion_FullSemVer* property to a text file after the GetVersionTask is run. This data is then used in the wix project for versioning the msi file.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. This might have worked, but I didn't want to write out a text file if I could avoid it. I hate using the file system as a temporary variable! Luckily, I figured out what I think is a more elegant solution and I have posted it as a separate answer.